# Is it ok to save an intent in the savedInstanceState

Tags: android

In my activity, user can open another activity. In the app workflow, user goes back to the original activity again, after doing some tasks in the newly opened activity.

I have a requirement where it is needed to open this other activity again, in the same state it was last opened. I currently do this by saving the intent used to open the new activity in a class variable `mXYZActivityIntent`. I save this variable in `onSaveInstanceState()` and restore it if available in `onCreate()`

```
Intent mXYZActivityIntent = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //...........

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mXYZActivityIntent = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("XYZ_INTENT");
    }
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    if (mXYZActivityIntent != null) {
        savedInstanceState.putParcelable("XYZ_INTENT", mXYZActivityIntent);
    }
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

A user has recently reported a crash that is related to this functionality. The crash has occurred in below line.

```
mXYZActivityIntent.putExtra("ABC", 0);
```

I tried to recreate this in multiple devices, and the above line gets executed without no problem at all.

Below stack is the only thing I have to analyze this.

```
android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.lahiruchandima.myApp.MyState
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2077)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1965)
at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
at android.os.Bundle.putInt(Bundle.java:443)
at android.content.Intent.putExtra(Intent.java:5393)
at com.lahiruchandima.myApp.MyActivity.undo(MyActivity.java:492)
at com.lahiruchandima.myApp.MyActivity$6.onClick(MyActivity.java:321)
at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:169)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5392)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`com.lahiruchandima.myApp.MyState` above is a class which implements `Parcellable`. An object of it is also stored in the `mXYZActivityIntent`. Seems like android fails to read `MyState` out of `mXYZActivityIntent`

I searched about this `BadParcelableException` and as I have understood, this is related to the class loader. But I am unable to figure out what I am doing wrong.

Can someone give me a clue about which may be going wrong?

Comment: why dont u just save the extra of that intent? cause all the information required to restore your state are in the extra right?

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin there are lot of information saved in the intent, where some of them are taken from the UI element values. With my apps logc, it is not suitable to save everything in  `MyState` parcellable. I used this approach because it is much easier to save the intent itself, instead of using another parcellable.

Comment: @LahiruChandima Have you got any clue?